# iOS Firemonkey: How to send email from iOS App though mail app in Firemonkey Delphi XE7

Tags: ios, delphi, email, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am working with iOS App in Firemonkey using Delphi XE7.

**Question:** I need to send email from my iOS App through the mail app in Firemonkey.

I have seen other old blogs for sending an email but those solutions didn't help me.

Below are the old links which I have tried it, but I couldn't solve.

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2011/10/04/39133

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/matthiaseissing/2013/05/03/38707/

Kindly let me know some other solutions or samples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second link (Matthias Eissing) is the right way to go. I think it is only the NSStr/NSURL conversion that fails? (because Embarcadero made changes to this in the latest Delphi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code from the second link you included:
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/matthiaseissing/2013/05/03/38707/

It is for XE4 and you just need a few changes to make it work for XE7:

The `StrToNSUrl` function has moved to the `Macapi.Helpers` unit in XE7, so you must add that to your uses clause. In addition the NSStr function is deprecated and so you should use `StrToNSStr` instead (also from Macapi.Helpers).

Here is a function that puts all the functionality together:

```
procedure SendEmail(aEmail: string; aSubject: string = ''; aBody: string = '');
var lSharedApplication: UIApplication;
    lURL: string;
begin
  lURL := 'mailto:'+aEmail;
  if (aSubject<>'') or (aBody<>'') then
  begin
    lURL := lURL+'?subject='+aSubject;
    if aBody<>'' then
      lURL := lURL+'&body='+aSubject;
    lURL := StringReplace(lURL,' ','%20',[rfReplaceAll]); //replace spaces
    lURL := StringReplace(lURL,sLineBreak,'%0D%0A',[rfReplaceAll]);//replace linebreaks
  end;
  lSharedApplication := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.SharedApplication);
  lSharedApplication.openURL(StrToNSUrl(lURL));
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
SendEmail('name@email.nowhere','My subject','My body');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hans. Could also help me to fix the space problem in the subject and the body of the email URL? How could we replace the space in the URL?

Comment: You should use the the HTML encoding for space=%20. Just replace all spaces with '%20' using StringReplace (in the SysUtils unit):
SharedApplication.openURL(StrToNSUrl(StringReplace(URL,' ','%20',[rfReplaceAll])));

Comment: Thanks again @Hans. The only problem I have is 'line break' in the email body section. I came to know that I have to use the %0D%0A for line breaks, but I don't exactly how and where to use it correctly.

Comment: I have modified the answer to handle line breaks too

Comment: the updated one is more precise. But sLineBreak variable was not declared in this procedure. That's the only thing is bit confused.

Comment: `sLineBreak` is defined in System and should work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the TDPFMailCompose class that is included in [D.P.F Delphi iOS Native Components](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/)

That gives you more options than a mailto: link and you don't have to worry about the encoding. Internally this uses the iOS MFMailComposeViewController class.

Example:

```
var
  Mail: TDPFMailCompose;
begin
  Mail := TDPFMailCompose.Create(nil);
  if not Mail.MailCompose(Msg.Subject, Msg.Body, False, [Msg.To_], [Msg.CC], [Msg.BCC], [AttachedFileName]) then
     MessageDlg('Error sending mail', TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbClose], -1);
end;
```